# Double or decimal for latitude/longitude values in C#

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, geopoints

What is the best data type to use when storing geopositional data in C#? I would use decimal for its exactness, but operations on decimal floating point numbers are slower then binary floating point numbers (double).

I read that most of the time you won't need any more than 6 or 7 digits of precision for latitude or longitude. Does the inexactness of doubles even matter then or can it be ignored?

Comment: I'd ask the opposite question: Does the performance difference even matter or can it be ignored?

Comment: Decimal for absolute precision. If you are storing millions on them, you can save a bit on size and improve a bit on performance using double, but negligible.

Comment: In database you should use "sql spatial data type" to store longitude and latitude

Comment: Note that the .NET BCL itself uses doubles in its [GeoCoordinate class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.100).aspx), which is a strong indication that the precision might be sufficient.

Comment: NodaTime's TzdbZoneLocation uses double as well.

Comment: double vs decimal = 32bits vs 128bits = 4 bytes vs 16 bytes

Comment: 1) I'd consider fixed-point. 2) Since you often need to do trigonometric operations on geo coordinates, and those are only implemented for `double`, `double` might be the best fit.

Comment: @Franck Small correction...double is a 64-bit number. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx#Remarks

Answer (score 172):

Go for `double`, there are several reasons.

- Trigonometric functions are available only for double
- Precision of double (range of 100 nanometers) is far beyond anything you'll ever require for Lat/Lon values
- [GeoCoordinate Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx) and third-Party modules (e.g. [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial)) also use double for coordinates

Answer (score 109):

A double has up to 15 decimal digits of precision. So, lets assume three of those digits are going to be on the left of the decimal point for lat/long values (max of 180deg). This leaves 12 digits of precision on the right. Since a degree of lat/long is ~111km, 5 of those 12 digits would give us precision to the meter. 3 more digits would give us precision to the millimeter. The remaining 4 digits would get us precision to around 100 nanometers. Since double will win from the perspective of performance and memory, I see no reason to even consider using decimal.

Comment: Plus one for a detailed and precise explanation.

Comment: Exactly the explanation I wanted to see, thanks!

Comment: You've convinced me to change from team Decimal to team Double for coordinates. Thanks for the well-constructed comment.

Answer (score 7):

I faced this question quite a while ago when i started with spacial programming. 
I read a book a while ago that led me to this.

```
//sql server has a really cool dll that deals with spacial data such like
//geography points and so on. 
//add this namespace
Using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
```

//SqlGeography.Point(dblLat, dblLon, srid)

```
var lat_lon_point = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(lat, lon, 4326);
```

This is the best way when working in your application with spacial data. 
then to save the data use this in sql

```
CREATE TABLE myGeoTable
{
LatLonPoint GEOMETRY 
}
```

else, if you are using something else that isnt sql just convert the point to hexadecimal and store it. I know after a long time using spacial that this is the safest.

Comment: I am having trouble finding LatLonPoint, what references or packages did you have to include or what 'usings' in your c# project? (assuming the create table was for Identity model / c# code, because that type doesn't evaluate  in SSMS either). thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Double

Combining the answers, it is how Microsoft represents it itself in SqlGeography library

```
[get: Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMethod(IsDeterministic=true, IsPrecise=true)]
public System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble Lat { get; }
```

Property Value

**SqlDouble**

A SqlDouble value that specifies the latitude.